# How to dynamically create a list of lists based on the byte size of the elements in a list

Tags: java

How can we create a list of lists based on the size in bytes of the elements in the list?

Given I have List values.  I want to split this list into multiple lists based on the sum of the byte size of the elements.

```
List<List<String>> splitList(List<String> listToSplit, int maxByteSize)
```

Assuming I have a ListlistToSplit = Arrays.asList("Value1", "Value2", "Value3"));

And the maxByteSize = 12.

Then I would expect to get 2 Lists - one list containing Value1 and Value2 and the other Value3

This is what I have tried so far

```
  private List<List<String>> splitList( List<String> values, int maxByteSize) {
    List<List<String>> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
    returnList = buildValuesList(maxByteSize, values.size(), values, returnList);
    return returnList;
}

    private List<List<String>> buildList(int availableSize, int noOfValues, List<String> values,
        List<List<String>> returnList) {
    List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> remainderValues = new ArrayList<>(values);
    returnList.add(valuesList);
       int currentSize = 0;
        for (String val : values) {
            int valueSize = val.getBytes().length;
            if (currentSize < availableSize && (currentSize + valueSize < availableSize)) {
                currentSize += valueSize;
                valuesList.add(val);
                remainderValues.remove(val);
            } else {
                buildValuesList(availableSize, noOfValues, remainderValues, returnList);
            }
        }
    return returnList;
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Did you mean `char`s instead of `byte`s?

Comment: Amended question with what i have tried. I need the byte size. So can do String.getBytes().length. ATM i am not considering the charset

Comment: What's your method `buildValuesList()`?

Comment: I've amended my post and added the splitList method which invokes the buildValuesList.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the listToSplit and if the sum between the bytes length of the current element and the bytes length of previous elements is greater than the `maxByteSize` then add the current list to the list to return and reset the length counter of the strings added to the list to return

```
public List<List<String>> splitList(List<String> listToSplit, int maxByteSize) {
    List<List<String>> splittedList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> currentList = new ArrayList<>();
    int currentSize = 0;
    for (String in : listToSplit) {

        if (currentSize + in.getBytes().length > maxByteSize) {
            splittedList.add(currentList);
            currentList = new ArrayList<>();
            splittedList.add(currentList); // add the new list to the list to return
            currentSize = 0;
        }
        currentSize += in.getBytes().length;
        currentList.add(in);
    }
    return splittedList;
}
```

Comment: That does not work. With this Unit test, we have only 1 list returned when it should be 2 e.g.   
  public void testSplitList() {
        String[] values = {"value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5"};
        List<List<String>> lists = splitList(Arrays.asList(values), 18);
        assertThat(lists.size(), equalTo(2));
    }

Comment: I've updated the answer, when the `currentList` was reinitialized it was not added to the `splittedList`

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what i needed